# Is the outlook rest api completely private?

Tags: azure-active-directory, outlook-restapi

I want to use the MS Graph REST api (v1.0) to pull email and calendar data from my work account based on the sample code here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-send-mail

I want to assume that, when I send a request, the work email server will send the response directly to me, and that at no time will this sensitive data ever hit a public azure server or a private microsoft one that isn't a part of the work ecosystem. Is this a safe assumption to make? I would assume that I am being overly paranoid, however the need to register with azure ad makes me wonder if I am interfacing with some external services and I need to be 100% sure the data will be secure.

Comment: I would expect that examination of the relevant Python source-code would answer your question conclusively.  It would certainly surprise me if the code contacted any e-mail server or external server other than the one you name ... but, since you do have the source-code, you can in fact be certain.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. I am not asking what the app does. I am asking if there is any risk after sending a request. E.g. my flask app sends a request along the lines of 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events', can I guarantee that when the email server responds, the response is exposed only to my app and not another server for, say, authentication or other purposes.

Comment: Of course you have no way to know what *else* the mail-server might do with your message before sending it back to you.  If you need true privacy, you need to encrypt the messages in question so that any other process, anywhere, which handles the message cannot divine anything from it.

Comment: Do you say that due to the fact that the mail-server may have custom handling of such events different from a vanilla O365 setup? or because we cannot have any guarantees on the way that the API behaves due to lack of transparency on how it works.

Comment: You really don't say what your "secrecy" requirements are.  If the traffic is passing directly to a private, trustworthy mail-server and directly back to you, through a known-secure link such as VPN (or even SSL/TLS in some cases), then you are fine as you are.  But, "categorically, 'e-mail' should not be presumed to be secure," because the traffic might pass through more than one "hop," thus more than one external system, on its way to/from you.  (Google, of course, makes a business of it.)  I say, "categorically," but I can't know from here what *your* case is.